# Есть ли список сокращённых названий городов на английском?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба

Есть такой список? Наверняка, уже давно у каждого города есть сокращённое английское обозначение.

Comment: Даже у Гусь-Хрустального?

Comment: Хотя бы города-милионники?

Comment: Что мешает использовать полные названия на английском? Убрать спецсимволы, привести к нижнему регистру, заменить пробелы подчеркиваниями - и вуаля)

Comment: Например, Санкт-Петербург spb - красиво получается... Поэтому и спрашиваю, может есть какой-нить стандарт?

Comment: называйте их кодами регионов россии.  78 вместо spb

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать трёхсимвольные IATA-коды аэропортов.

http://airspot.ru/catalogue/airports/country/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: уже совсем как-то не подходит...

Comment: правда у относительно мало городов с аэропортами

Comment: В городах-миллионниках аэропорты точно есть.

Comment: А ещё есть какие-нибудь предложения? Нужно для ЧПУ

Comment: @ArchieO'Hare, ага.. а потом пусть пользователи догадываются мол KUF - это Самара ) редко строят аэропорты прямо в городах. В основном в городах-спутниках, отсюда и такие "странные" сокращения.

Comment: Например, кто придумал, что Москва - msk, а Санкт-Петербург - spb?

Comment: Вообще тема актуальна давно, вот топик на форуме 10-летней давности: http://xpoint.ru/forums/searching/thread/33844.xhtml ;)